# Looking for an elementary proof of the fact that a bijective morphism of smooth varieties is an isomorphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X,Y$ be smooth varieties over $\mathbb{C}$, and $f:X\to Y$ be a bijective morphism. Then it is true that $f$ is in fact an isomorphism. The only proof that I know of this fact uses some fairly non-trivial results, and makes me wonder if there is some elementary way to see this?

It is clear that $f$ has an analytic inverse, using the analytic inverse function theorem. So my question is essentially, why does the inverse function theorem in this situation produce an algebraic function?

Comment: Is the analytic statement + GAGA really not sufficient? In any case, I think the claim is true over any field of characteristic 0. I recall that you can use Zariski's main theorem to prove something like that. (In fact I think that proof was on MO somewhere.) It doesn't qualify as elementary but it's elegantly formal.

Comment: Stacks suggests a different argument (still not really elementary): $f$ is analytically étale hence étale. Thus the relative diagonal $X \rightarrow X \times_Y X$ is an open immersion. It is surjective on $\mathbb{C}$-points hence surjective, hence an isomorphism. Thus the first projection $p_1: X \times_Y X \rightarrow X$ is an isomorphism. Therefore $f$ is bijective, open (because flat because étale) so a homeomorphism so quasi-compact. So $f$ is a fpqc cover and the isomorphism $p_1$ is a base change of $f$ by $f$ so by descent (not trivial but not too scary iirc) $f$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @Jeroen: GAGA requires your varieties to be projective.  This result is true much more generally (though the only proof I know uses Zariski’s main theorem, like you suggest).

Comment: One can prove the following statement in algebra. To apply it one needs to reduce to the affine case.

Work over a field $k$. Given a morphism $f:R\to S$ of finite type $k$-algebras such that for *every* finite dimensional (as a vector space) $k$-algebra $A$, the induced map $f^{*}:\mathrm{Hom}(S,A)\to\mathrm{Hom}(R,A)$ is a bijection. Then $f$ is an isomorphism.

In your case, since $X$ and $Y$ are smooth and $k=\mathbb{C}$, the condition for general $A$ follows from the fact that the morphism is a bijection on points.